# Trying to create a package for debian with java

Tags: java, dependencies, debian, package, pbuilder

I'm trying to create a package which depends exactly on `sun-java6-jre` (other variants don't work in this case) and build-depends on `sun-java6-jdk`. Unfortunately pbuilder doesn't want to work this way:

1. it installs `openjdk-6-jre` as a dependency
2. it returns `pbuilder-satisfydepends-dummy: Depends: sun-java6-jdk which is a virtual package.`

Which I don't understand since this is not a virtual package and my `debian/control` explicitly lists:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7), sun-java6-jdk, sun-java6-jre, java2-runtime, java-virtual-machine, libunixsocket-java, ant
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, sun-java6-jre, cron, sqlite3, libunixsocket-java
```

I'm using the `pbuilder` environment with basic lenny.

Comment: I think that it would be more adapted to ask this question on http://www.superuser.com

Comment: @Colin - disagree: (from FAQ): "What kind of questions can I ask here?" "... # software tools commonly used by programmers ; # matters that are unique to the programming profession" - creating specific packages and resolving the dependency problems from the point of view of package maintainer belongs here more than to SU.

Comment: I meant that maybe the people on superuser know this kind of problem better than developers. That's why I didn't even report this, it was just an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled non-free repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list inside the pbuilder chroot?

Comment: That did the trick, I believe. Not sure why the package was reported as "virtual" though.